# Determine which Kendo UI version and product I"m working with

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've started as a new dev in a team where all previous devs have left and as usual it's not easy to find information.

The project is asp.net MVC 4.

There is a reference to a dll : Kendo.Mvc.dll

The project has the following script files:

- kendo.aspnetmvc.min
- kendo.core.min
- kendo.data.min
- kendo.data.odata.min
- kendo.data.xml.min
- kendo.grid.min
- kendo.web.min

And also includes jquery and jquery-ui (1.10).

Question:

- How do I know if the product was purchased or the kind of licence this is ? (all dependencies have been put into source control, I can't find any obvious key file or something like that in the config).
- How do I know which version of the product it is ? (this one I think I've got the answer, the DLL version says: 2013.2.xxx so that's probably it)
- Where can I download the old versions of the scripts ?

I'm very confused about the state of those components. It seems like Telerik acquired Kendo a while ago and this project has old version.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the DLL version is the Kendo UI version (or more precisely, the [UI for ASP.NET MVC](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/kendo-ui-vs-mvc-wrappers) version). In more recent versions, the DLL description explicitly states if it is a trial version or not.

In addition, Kendo UI JavaScript files and CSS files have their version in a comment at the top of the file contents, e.g.

http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css

> /**
>
> * Kendo UI v2016.3.914 (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui)
>
> * Copyright 2016 Telerik AD. All rights reserved.

Another possible way to check the scripts version in the web application or browser console is via [`kendo.version`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#fields-version) - the API docs also explains the meaning of the version number.

The DLL version should always match the version of the JavaScript and CSS files (except the last part of the DLL version, which is related to the ASP.NET MVC version).

> It seems like Telerik acquired Kendo a while ago

Kendo UI has always been a product of Telerik.

It is possible to download previous versions' installers from telerik.com if you have the email for account that has held the commercial license.

Answer (score 3):

you can print it in the console

```
    <!-- Telerik KendoUI Default v2 CDN 2019 -->
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common-empty.min.css" rel="stylesheet-disabled" />
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet-disabled" />
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.default-v2.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet-disabled" />

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Print jQuery, kendoUI version
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('Detected jQuery version: %o', $().jquery);
            console.log('Detected Telerik KendoUI version: %o', kendo.version);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version is indeed in the DLL.

Missing scripts can be found and downloaded from cdn.kendostatic.com

Only mistery remaining is the licence... not sure it's worth investigating.